# Istio Proxies unable to communicate with istiod

Tags: amazon-web-services, istio, amazon-eks

Some of our istio proxies are getting authentication errors trying to talk to istiod

```
warn    sds failed to warm certificate: failed to generate workload certificate: create certificate: rpc error: code = Unauthenticated desc = request authenticate failure
```

This is only happening on some worker nodes and not others. The k8s cluster is an AWS EKS cluster. This is happening out of the blue and not after any major change. We have AWS support and they are saying it's an Istio problem not and EKS issue.

Comment: Did you see [this topic](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/23364)?